# Need to write a query instead of 5 queries to get the result of all 5 states

Tags: mysql, sql, database, groupwise-maximum

[image]

The CSV file has around 62000 rows, It has states and county (county name is unique within that particular state).

I had to write 5 queries on the view. Each query will retrieve for one of the states the State_Name, Date, MAX(SumConfirmed) the date with the highest number of confirmed cases in each state.

```
SELECT State_Name, Date, ConfirmedCases AS Max_ConfirmedCases
FROM covid_by_state
WHERE ConfirmedCases =
    (SELECT max(ConfirmedCases) AS Max_ConfirmedCases
     FROM covid_by_state
     WHERE State_Name='Texas');
```

The above query was giving me the result for one particular state but I'm not able to find how to get the result of 5 states in one query.

Comment: This is the view that I have created
CREATE VIEW COVID_BY_STATE AS 
SELECT Date, State_Name, Sum(Daily_Count_Cases) as ConfirmedCases, Sum(Daily_Deaths) as DailyDeath
FROM Covid_By_County
GROUP BY Date, State_Name;

Comment: STATE TABEL
CREATE TABLE state (
 State_Name VARCHAR(50),
    State_Cap_City VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (State_Name)
);

Comment: COUNTY TABLE
CREATE TABLE county (
 County_Name VARCHAR(50),
    State_Name VARCHAR(50),
    FOREIGN KEY (State_Name) REFERENCES state (State_Name),
    PRIMARY KEY (County_Name, State_Name)
);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a *correlated* subquery:

```
SELECT cbs.State_Name, cbs.Date, cbs.ConfirmedCases as Max_ConfirmedCases
FROM covid_by_state cbs
WHERE cbs.ConfirmedCases = (SELECT max(cbs2.ConfirmedCases) 
                            FROM covid_by_state cbs2
                            WHERE cbs2.State_Name = cbs.State_Name
                           );
```

This returns the rows for *all* the states at the same time.

EDIT:

If you want all dates with the maximum for a particular state, then you can use aggregation:

```
SELECT cbs.State_Name, GROUP_CONCAT(cbs.Date) as dates,
       cbs.ConfirmedCases as Max_ConfirmedCases
FROM covid_by_state cbs
WHERE cbs.ConfirmedCases = (SELECT max(cbs2.ConfirmedCases) 
                            FROM covid_by_state cbs2
                            WHERE cbs2.State_Name = cbs.State_Name
                           )
GROUP BY cbs.State_Name, cbs.ConfirmedCases
```

Comment: I think this (and the questioner's original answer) don't work correctly if two states have the same maximum ConfirmedCases

Comment: To avoid dups, see  _some_ of the solutions in mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max

Comment: @ysth . . . The OP is not clear on what to do in that situation.  Given that the existing query returns rows for *any* state whose number of cases is matches the maximum of the particular state, this is definitely an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

I'm skipping the using the view; I don't think it adds any value in readability, and won't work if you want to start restricting the query to some date range or add other criteria anyway.

```
select
    State_Name,
    max_confirmed_cases_date as Date,
    max(ConfirmedCases) as Max_ConfirmedCases
from (
    select
        State_Name,
        first_value(Date) over (partition by State_Name order by ConfirmedCases desc, Date) max_confirmed_cases_date, 
        ConfirmedCases
    from (
        select Date, State_Name, sum(Daily_Count_Cases) ConfirmedCases
        from Covid_By_County
        group by Date, State_Name
    ) daily_state_totals
) daily_state_totals_with_max_cases_date
group by State_Name, max_confirmed_cases_date
```

The innermost subselect is equivalent to your view; it gets one row per state per date with a total of cases.  The middle subselect repeats every row of that, but instead of date, uses first_value() to find the date for that state with the highest number of cases (preferring earlier to later dates in cases of ties).  The outer select then reduces it to one row per state.

Or if you are on an older version that doesn't support window functions:

```
select
    State_Name,
    date(substr(min(concat(99999999999-ConfirmedCases,Date)),12)) as Date,
    max(ConfirmedCases) as Max_ConfirmedCases
from (
    select Date, State_Name, sum(Daily_Count_Cases) ConfirmedCases
    from Covid_By_County
    group by Date, State_Name
) daily_state_totals
group by State_Name
```

This query uses a trick to get the date with maximum cases for each state by getting the minimum of a string that encodes both the cases and date.